# Phalcon Multi-Module Routing

Tags: php, phalcon

Im attempting to use the multi module configuration for the Phalcon PHP Framework.

Im having an issue relating to the routing as one of my modules is inaccessible via url. It seems every time I try to access the defined modules uri, it tries to invoke the default modules namespace. `Project\Module1\Controllers\Module2Controller handler class cannot be loaded`

The idea solution

```
url.com/module1  => module1
url.com/moudle2  => module2
url.com          => module1
```

In working to resolve this problem, I have verified that all paths and namespaces are correct. Ive combed through it with xdebug.

Ive created my project with Phalcon Devtools with the multi module type defined as it provided me with a skeleton to follow. As I am using this method, it provided a default routing method that interprets each registered module and binds it to a url. This does not seem to be working for me.  This is the Phalcon project before interpretation. https://github.com/phalcon/phalcon-devtools/tree/master/templates/project/modules

**Routing**

https://github.com/phalcon/phalcon-devtools/blob/master/templates/project/modules/routes.php

```
$router = $di->get("router");

foreach ($application->getModules() as $key => $module) {
    $namespace = str_replace('Module','Controllers', $module["className"]);
    $router->add('/'.$key.'/:params', array(
        'namespace' => $namespace,
        'module' => $key,
        'controller' => 'index',
        'action' => 'index',
        'params' => 1
    ))->setName($key);
    $router->add('/'.$key.'/:controller/:params', array(
        'namespace' => $namespace,
        'module' => $key,
        'controller' => 1,
        'action' => 'index',
        'params' => 2
    ));
    $router->add('/'.$key.'/:controller/:action/:params', array(
        'namespace' => $namespace,
        'module' => $key,
        'controller' => 1,
        'action' => 2,
        'params' => 3
    ));
}
```

**Module Registration**

https://github.com/phalcon/phalcon-devtools/blob/master/templates/project/modules/modules.php

```
$application->registerModules(array(
    'module1' => array(
        'className' => 'Project\Module1\Module',
        'path' => __DIR__ . '/../apps/module1/Module.php'
    ),
    'module2' => array(
        'className' => 'Project\Module2\Module',
        'path' => __DIR__ . '/../apps/module2/Module.php'
    )
));
```

**Service**

https://github.com/phalcon/phalcon-devtools/blob/master/templates/project/modules/services.php

```
$di->set('router', function () {
$router = new Router();

$router->setDefaultModule('module1');
$router->setDefaultNamespace('Project\Module1\Controllers');

 return $router;
});
```

An example provided by Phalcon. This not exact to the Phalcon Tools implementation.

https://github.com/phalcon/mvc/tree/master/multiple-factory-default

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I struggled with this yesterday. If I used a default module and then defined a route like `/:module/:controller/:action/:params` I had to use something like `/my-module/index/index`. What I had to do was define a `Group` with a default module and then put each controller and it's index in manually.

Comment: Can you add an example please?

Answer (score 3):

I have my general routes defined in `app\config\routes.php` then in `app\config\routes` I have one file for each of the groups (in this case modules).

**app\config\routes.php**

```
<?php
$router = new \Phalcon\Mvc\Router();

$router->setDefaultModule("frontend");

$router->add("/:module/:controller/:action/:params", array(
    'module' => 1,
    'controller' => 2,
    'action' => 3,
    'params' => 4
));

foreach (glob(__DIR__ . "/routes/*.php") as $filename) {
    include $filename;
}

$router->removeExtraSlashes(true);

return $router;
```

**admin\config\routes\admin.php**

```
<?php

use Phalcon\Mvc\Router\Group;

//Create a group with a common module and controller
$admin = new Group(array('module' => 'admin'));

$admin->setPrefix('/admin');

$admin->add("", array(
    'controller' => 'index',
    'action' => 'index'
));

$admin->add("/foo", array(
    'controller' => 'foo',
    'action' => 'index'
));

$admin->add("/bar", array(
    'controller' => 'bar',
    'action' => 'index'
));

$router->mount($admin);
```

I have only had to define the controller and index because any other actions will be part of the url and should route by themselves.

### EDIT

**index.php**

```
/*
 * ... includes
 */

$application = new \Phalcon\Mvc\Application($di);

$application->registerModules(array(
    'admin' => array(
        'className' => 'Calmsplash\App\Admin',
        'path' => '../app/admin/Admin.php',
    ),
    'frontend' => array(
        'className' => 'Calmsplash\App\Frontend',
        'path' => '../app/frontend/Frontend.php',
    ),
    /// ... more modules
));
```

I've called my `Module` files after the module name just to fit them into the namespace.

Comment: what does your boot strap file look like? Thanks for the help btw