# Different directories and namespaces for controllers in Phalcon

Tags: model-view-controller, phalcon

I want to be able to build a small app (e.g. a basic login MVC structure) and structure my [Phalcon](https://phalconphp.com/en/) project such that I can just drop it in one folder and tweak the `config` file a bit.

E.g. I have my basic login app built from the [Vokuro](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/tutorial-vokuro.html) tutorial. Now rather than copying controllers to one directory, models to another, etc in order to deploy it in my existing app I want to drop it into a folder (e.g. `app/extensions/security`) and then tweak my main `config`/`bootstrap` so that the requests for `Users` or `Profiles` are directed to the controllers in `app/extensions/security/controllers`.

Everything is namespaced according to the folder structure and my current `loader` looks like:

```
$loader->registerNamespaces(array(
    'Me\Controllers' => $config->application->controllersDir,
    'Me\Models' => $config->application->modelsDir,
    'Me\Forms' => $config->application->formsDir,
    'Me' => $config->application->libraryDir,
    'Me\Security' => $config->application->extensionsDir . 'security/'
));
```

Basically - how do I make Phalcon look in `app/controllers` for some controllers and in another directory for others (`app/extensions/security/controllers`)?

I am not sure if this is explained sufficiently well - if clarification is needed, please tell me.

**Edit**

I've got the login page showing by adding this to my routes

```
$router->add('/session/:action', array(
    'namespace' => 'Me\Security\Controllers',
    'controller' => 'Session',
    'action' => 1
));
```

So I think I will create a routes file in my `app/extensions/security` folder and then load that in the main bootstrap file.

Comment: Do you have namespaces set in your router?

Comment: I've just tried that and got things going, thanks. I think a routes file for each extension is probably the way to go that is then loaded by the main bootstrap file.

Comment: @JamesFenwick Any idea about an easy way to make those controllers find the correct view files? At the moment I'm thinking about putting the details into the extension specific config file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be a good idea to move to a multi module application. I explained how I did it at [Phalcon Multi-Module Routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31463553/phalcon-multi-module-routing/31475390#31475390).

You would be able to set all the routes, view directories, separate configs, etc. for your security module in one place.

It is fine to extend from your security base class, you already extend from `Phalcon\Mvc\Model` so it's no different.

You could do something like this:

```
<?php
namespace My\Controllers;

use My\Security\Controllers\ControllerBase as SecurityBase;

class ControllerBase extends SecurityBase
{
...
```

Comment: Thanks, going to take a look at that now. After a quick look I have one question though - would this make it possible for classes in one module to inherit from classes in another module? Every class in the `main app` should inherit from the `ControllerBase` in the `security module` as that implements the `Auth` / `ACL` checks.